# Git submodule: Modify External Library and push to inhouse repository & Preserve Updatability

Tags: git, git-submodules

We want to extend an opensource project and modify it. But want to preserve updatability of version of this opensource project. We do some other stuff in our repository (working on some plugins) how ever it is not important...

git submodule allows us to have external repository and update it. but after spending sometime we figured out if we modify external library we should push it to it's own repository and we cannot push it to our repository. I other words, We want to push to our server to be able to work as a team. but can also pull from library repository.
need your help...

Comment: GIt submodules are really hard to work with. Do you use any build tools that can download dependencies? For instance, composer for PHP, Maven for Java etc?

Comment: No, we do not. (it is a PHP project) We need to modify external library and rebase on new releases...

Comment: Why not just make a fork of this library?

Answer (score 1):

The git submodule is not really easy to use with external libraries coming from different sources. I would prefer the `git external` at http://danielcestari.com/git-external/ as it's much more simpler.

Assumed you have the /your-project that uses a forked open-source library. You can configure your project as follows:

```
git clone <your-git-project> your-project
cd your-project
```

Fork the open-source library and link it to your project

```
git external add <forked-opensource-library-git-url> forked-opensrc-lib
git commit .gitignore .gitexternals -m "Setup to use forked library xyz"
git external init
git push
```

To push all changes in the local to the forked library, use the following command:

```
git external 'git push'
```

In the team environment, you can pull all updates from the remote, including your-project and the forked library:

```
git pull
git external update
```

When you want to contribute your code to the open source library, you then can make a pull request from your forked lib to the original open-source lib

Answer (score 0):

Git submodule checks out a specific commit, not a branch, which makes modifying the contents of the submodule difficult. After having used submodules for a while I've abandoned them in favor of a different approach: using project dependency management.
Here's an example layout using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md):

```
code/               # base directory
+ main-project/     # a big project depending on 3rd party libraries
| + .git/           # remotes: origin=private repository
| + composer.json   # lists PHP dependencies: forked-lib
+ forked-lib/       # a 3rd party open source lib with custom modifications
  + .git/           # remotes: origin=original repository, private=private repository
  + composer.json   # custom modification: declares this as a composer package
```

As you see, there are 2 projects: the `main-project`, and `forked-lib`, which allows to work on them separately.

The `main-project` specifies `forked-lib` as a dependency in a `composer.json` file, like this:

```
{
  "name": "company-name/main-project",
  "require": {
    "company-name/forked-lib" : "2.x-dev",
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url" : "https://private-repository/forked-lib.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

The dependency `company-name/forked-lib` has version `2.x-dev`, and Composer takes the `.x-dev` to mean that the version is on a particular branch (`v2` in this case; see [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches) for more information). It will check out that branch and look for a composer.json file with content like this:

```
{
  "name": "company/forked-lib",
  "version": "2.1"
}
```

When working on `forked-lib`, which has two remotes, upstream changes are `pull`ed from `origin`, and the local `v2` branch is rebased against them. Any commits made are pushed to the `private` repository. This includes marking new releases by upgrading the version in composer.json.

Running `composer install` will then checkout the dependency and 
store it in `vendor/company/forked-lib`, and running `composer update` will update the dependency if the version has increased.

Comment: Thank you @Kenny. I am trying to make it work by composer